# SQLite alias of table name in UPDATE statement

Tags: sqlite, alias

I have a SQLite table called Price like this:

```
date,     productId, price
----------------------
20120601, 10       , 10.1
20120601, 20       , 20.1
20120602, 10       , 0
20120602, 20       , 0
20120602, 30       , 0
```

The table is created with this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "Price" ("date" INTEGER NOT NULL , "productId" INTEGER NOT NULL , "price" DOUBLE, PRIMARY KEY ("date", "productId"))
```

I want to fill the price of date==20120602 with the price of the same product in the previous date.

i.e I want the table turn into like this:

```
date,     productId, price
----------------------
20120601, 10       , 10.1
20120601, 20       , 20.1
20120602, 10       , 10.1
20120602, 20       , 20.1
20120602, 30       , 0
```

So I tried this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE Price New SET New.price = 
    (SELECT old.price FROM Price Old WHERE New.date == 2 AND Old.date == 1 AND New.productId == Old.productId)
```

But SQLite gave me an error near dot.

Than I tried this statement:

```
UPDATE New Set New.Price = Old.Price
FROM Price New, Price Old
WHRER ......
```

SQLite gave me an error near FROM.

I double checked SQLite's SQL Syntax but found no lucky. Even I never tried so, I think both statements would work as expected in MS SQL Server. The first statement might work if New and Old are too different tables, but I need them in same table.

I really don't want to write a for loop to update once a line in my C++ code, I need advice on the right way to achieve this in SQLite.

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I myself have experienced this. Just remove word `New` after `UPDATE Price` and wherever you use `New.something` change to `Price.something`. I am sure there is a much nicer solution, but it works.

*updated with code snippet from comments...*

```
UPDATE Price 
SET
price = (SELECT old.price FROM Price Old WHERE Old.date = 1 AND price.productId = Old.productId) 
WHERE price.date = 2
```

Comment: I tried your solution, there's no syntax error any more, but the values are not changed. Would you please be more accurate on the sql statement I should use? Thank you.

Comment: And if I change Price column to allow NULL, every price will be set to NULL after I run `UPDATE Price SET price = (SELECT old.price FROM Price Old WHERE price.date == 2 AND Old.date == 1 AND price.productId == Old.productId)`, every data is lost......

Comment: What sense does it make to put `price.date == 2` in a subquery since it is completely unrelated to `old` table? Move it outside the subquery.

Comment: Should be: `UPDATE Price SET price = 
    (SELECT Old.price FROM Price Old WHERE Old.date = 1 AND Price.productId = Old.productId) WHERE date = 2`. By the way, just noticed, why were you using double `=`'s?

Comment: Good call, I moved `price.date == 2` outside and it works. The new statement is `UPDATE Price SET price = 
    (SELECT old.price FROM Price Old WHERE Old.date == 1 AND price.productId == Old.productId) WHERE price.date == 2 `

Comment: Thank you. I'm more a C++ programmer, I use `==` as that's how it works in C++. In SQL, it sames `==` and `=` are the same in `WHERE`

Comment: Ah actually didn't know `==` is allowed at all :) Happy I could help. Cheers!

Comment: I recently noticed a issue in this case, what if we have 1 log when date=1 and 2 logs when date=2? I've all column set to "Not NULL". So when I execute this statement, I got a `constraint failed` error. After Googled, I feel like I'm trying to insert NULL value to the table. So do you have any solution for this case?

Comment: If I understand you correctly and if I understand my answer correctly, I think the date must be unique. If you have two date changes in one day then I think you should somehow extend the date field. Seeing date as integer is pretty strange and I think you are using date type for that so I think extension for date would be adding time so you can add price twice a day.

Comment: I've updated my sample in the post to make things more clear. The PK of the table is `(date, productId)`. and every column in the table is `NOT NULL`.

Comment: I am really sorry, but do not understand what the problem is. Can you please try again explaining? I thought it got solved already.

Comment: Can you provide and example of the data of the new example?

Comment: Well I am reading the question and the answer one, two, three times. It is just not happening. I see nothing changed and the answer fits the question. Try putting another question if you are looking for something different than this question. And give me a link too :) I am sorry, but I just do not understand what you want :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English. I'll try to figure it out myself or with another post.